# Esper output explanations

Tags: esper

Consider the following event stream and context definitions:

```
create schema EventCreated(
    source String,
    type String,
    time String,
    value Integer
);

create context Trip
    context bySource
        partition by source from EventCreated,

    context byEvents
        initiated by EventCreated(
            type = "IgnitionOn") as startEvent

        terminated by EventCreated(
            type = "IgnitionOff") as endEvent;
```

I would like, when my context end, to select is beginning and ending date, that is to say the "time" property from startEvent and endEvent respectively.

My first attempt was this:

```
context Trip
    select
        context.byEvents.startEvent.time as startTime,
        context.byEvents.endEvent.time as endTime

    from
        EventCreated e

    output
        snapshot when terminated;
```

However, when I tried it, all I had as a result was an "empty" statement:

```
At: 2016-10-07 10:20:00.000
Statement: Stmt-3
```

After a few attempts, I realised that if I didn't selected anything from EventCreated itself, the output was always empty, for example, if I do:

```
context Trip
    select
        avg(e.value) as averageValue,
        context.byEvents.startEvent.time as startTime,
        context.byEvents.endEvent.time as endTime

    from
        EventCreated e

    output
        snapshot when terminated;
```

then I indeed get a not-empty result (with the same events incoming, of course):

```
At: 2016-10-07 10:20:00.000
Statement: Stmt-3
Insert
Stmt-3-output={averageValue=3.0, startTime='2016-10-07T10:00:00.000', endTime=(null)}
```

So, my first question is this one: What's the syntax I sould use if I don't want to select anything from the events, only from the context itself when it ends? Is snapshot the wrong keyword here? Is there a way to select something only from a context and not for an event stream?

Also, as you can see, although I can retrieve data from my "initiating" event (the one declared by "initiated by" in my context declaration), I can never retrieve data from my "terminating" event. Am I doing something wrong here?

I know I could do this:

```
context Trip
    select
        context.byEvents.startEvent.time as startTime,
        e.time as endTime

    from
        EventCreated e

    output
        last when terminated;
```

but I'd really like to know what's wrong with my syntax cause it feels correct.

Answer (score 0):

"Output snapshot" gives the same as "iterate()" results. The "from EventCreated" doesn't retain any events and the "iterate()" result is therefore empty. What you are looking for are all the events so do "from EventCreated.win:keepall()" instead.

When "avg()" is added you have whats called a ungrouped full-aggregated query and that does "iterate()" to return a single row which is the average.

Its probably overkill to use a nested context for this and just "initiatedBy" with "from EventCreated(id = context.startEvent.Id)" instead.

Comment: If I use .win:keepall(), I got one output for every event, that's not what I want. I want one "summary" output for my context, but no aggregation data, just some details from my first and last events.

I don't understand how to write my problem with your example, could you elaborate please?